# Setter Injection for fields that are only supposed to be set once

Tags: dependency-injection

I know that a lot of DI frameworks prefer to use Setter Injection over Constructor Injection. But what about fields that are only supposed to be set once during object creation? Do I simply have to trust that nobody sets another value during runtime?

Comment: Why do you think that frameworks prefer setter injection?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken a lot of frameworks started out using setter injection and added support for constructor injection later on. I think the article i read was about spring.

Comment: You're right. I think your answer is in here: http://spring.io/blog/2007/07/11/setter-injection-versus-constructor-injection-and-the-use-of-required/

Comment: The article talks about required dependencies, which is kind of what I'm asking for here. What interests me though, is how people handle setters that should only be called once.

Comment: Are you using a local default for those properties?  I guess you could have each setter throw an exception if its value has already been set.  But I strongly prefer constructor injection because then you don't have to worry about people doing things that they shouldn't.  Why do you want to use property injection instead of constructor injection?

Comment: I don't want to use property injection. I was just thinking how the case of "one time injection" would be handled when using setters instead of constructors.